# Optimization of query [Subtracting two specific rows Mysql]

Tags: mysql, optimization

```
SELECT (a.t_avg - b.t_avg) as t_diff, 
        (a.prcp - b.prcp) as prcp_diff, 
        a.county as county 
FROM (SELECT * FROM weather WHERE ob_date='2016-01-01') a 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM weather WHERE ob_date='2016-01-02') b 
  ON a.station_name = b.station_name 
GROUP BY a.county
```

I want the difference of temperature and precipitation in an efficient way for any two dates. Currently, Query is taking average 1.2 Mins

My table structure is

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| station_name | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| t_max        | float       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| t_min        | float       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| t_avg        | float       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| prcp         | float       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| geo_lat      | float(10,4) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| geo_long     | float(10,4) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ob_date      | date        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| county       | varchar(5)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Output of Explain
[image: Output of Explain statment]

Comment: What about the output of EXPLAIN? What indexes do you have, if you have none, why not?

Comment: @Harry I have added indexes for station_name, ob_date and geo_lat and geo_long combined. I have added explain output to post. Please check it

Comment: _"I want the difference of temperature and precipitation in an efficient way."_ - would it not make much more sense to calculate both those values _once_, at the time you insert a new record? "Yesterday", for most dates, should've happend already ... And even if perhaps updating a wrongly reported value once in a while is an issue, or you don't get your data in a chronological fashion from all input sources - might still be more efficient to handle that via a trigger maybe? (When a record is inserted or updated, check if there's a matching record for the next day, and then update that.)

Comment: @CBroe 2016-01-01 and 2016-01-02 are sample dates. I should able to compare any two dates data.

Comment: Not an SQL Expert, i wonder why those guys didnt answer. I think you should try to get rid of the "temporary" and "filesort", but i'd need to play around and do research for that myself. Also you group by country which is a varchar and doesnt have an index. Please create an index on country and tell me if your query did speed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use "derived tables" unless you need to.  Here's a way to reformulate it:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM weather AS a
    JOIN weather AS b  USING(station_name)
    WHERE a.ob_date='2016-01-01'
      AND b.ob_date='2016-01-01'
    GROUP BY ...
```

You should also have `INDEX(ob_date, station_name)`

The `country`, `lat`, etc since this does not every change for a given station, correct?  Then make a separate table to describe the stations.

```
CREATE TABLE Stations (
    station_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    station_name ...,
    lat, lng, country
    PRIMARY KEY station_id
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then your main table is much less bulky (hence somewhat faster):

```
CREATE TABLE Readings (
    station_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ob_date DATE NOT NULL,
    t_min FLOAT NOT NULL,
    t_avg FLOAT NOT NULL,
    prcp  FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ob_date, station_id),
    INDEX(station_id, ob_date)
```

`ob_date, station_id` is unique, correct?

(Will you need help converting your current schema to the new?  Will you need help with the additional `JOIN` to get country?)

(Please don't use `DESCRIBE` it is less descriptive that `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)